# geometry nodes - cut curves / insert vertices

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, geometry-nodes

I have build a quadraliteral curve with another quadraliteral curve as "notches". Is there any possible way to insert vertices at the point where the vertex / point of the one hit the other curve and cut them out?

[image: Notch1]
[image: overview]
[image: cutthis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also achieve the desired result by extruding your mesh or curve and then simply using the node `Mesh Boolean`.

In this example I used a different structure than you, but the principle can remain the same:

1. First extrude your mesh with the node `Extrude` or use `Curve to Mesh` if you still want to use curves.
2. Then create the difference between these two meshes with the node `Mesh Boolean`.
3. Since you only need the lower parts of the mesh, remove everything above the *Z position* $0$.
4. Finally you can convert the resulting mesh back to a curve with the node `Mesh to Curve`.

[image]

PS: By the way, with this technique you can easily select the points along your curve where you want the notches to be instantiated and where not (Input *Selection* of the node `Instance on Points`)

[image]

Comment: at first, i not will not use the bool node. :-/ but when i can it return to a curve - this is realy a nic setup! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see - there is actualy no possible way to bool two curves. :-/

The only way to get my result, without mesh boolean, is to draw all lines individuell... the result is this "node monster".

[image: Node]

[image: result]

Comment: This doesn't look particularly procedural, but still +1 in appreciation for your effort! ;-)